# I'm using Laravel + vue to pass variables to vue through Blade but it doesn't display

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

blade file (JSON):

```
@extends('layouts.app')
    
@section('content')
    <div>
        <test-component :items='{{ $items }}'></test-component>
    </div>
@endsection
```

vue component:

```
<template> 
    
    <ul id="example-1">
        <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
            {{ item.id }}
          </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    // Vue.js のインスタンス
    module.exports = new Vue({
        props: {
            items: {
                type: Object,
                defalut: {},
            },
        },
    })
</script>
```

Google developer tool:

```
 <ul id="example-1" items="[object Object],[object Object],[object
 Object],[object Object],</ul>
```

Warning:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "items" is not defined on the instance
> but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property.

The processing result will be like this. I don't know what mistake I made.

Comment: can you please explain this more? <ul id="example-1" items="[object Object],[object Object],[object
 Object],[object Object],</ul>

Comment: <ul id="example-1" items="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],</ul> 
It looks like this when using Google's developer tools.

Comment: what is $items in controller?

Comment: return view('chat.vue')->with('item', $items);
blade
 <chat-component v-bind:item='@json($items)'></chat-component>

Answer (score 0):

Just define your props as below. Why are you defining props like the above way?
`props:['items']`

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = new Vue({
```

The notation around here was wrong